# Swift protocol and extension, I need to call instance method if it present

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have a protocol Foo and its extension like this:

```
protocol Foo {
    func test()    
}

extension Foo {
    func test() {
        print("foo")
    }
}
```

And I also have classes from protocol like this:

```
class Bar: Foo {
    func test() {
        print("bar")
    }
}
```

And tester like below:

```
func tester<T: Foo>(_ obj: T) {
   obj.test()
}

let myBar = Bar()
tester(myBar)
```

In output I have:

> foo

But expected - bar

How I can call instance method `test()` from my `tester`

Comment: I tested this code in playgrounds and the output is "bar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on two things:

- Is this a requirement of the protocol or merely injected by an extension?
- Is the receiver typed as Foo or Bar?

So for example:

```
protocol Foo {
    // func test() // note we've commented this out!
}
extension Foo {
    func test() {
        print("foo")
    }
}
class Bar: Foo {
    func test() {
        print("bar")
    }
}
let myBar = Bar()
myBar.test() // bar
let myFoo : Foo = Bar()
myFoo.test() // foo
```

But if you uncomment the line that I commented out, now you *always* get `"bar"` printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare the function inside the protocol then it is dynamically dispatched using a witness table ie you will get the overridden version if you call it form a derived implementation.  If you **declare** the function in an extension (and its not declared in the protocol) then the function is statically dispatched and you get the version based on what type you are calling it on (ie no polymorphism).  The reason for this is that the compiler has to know the protocol function and variable declarations at compile time to generate the witness table, and it can't be aware of all possible extensions at compile time.